# Sending message to viewController in Tab Based Application (iphone iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking

I have a method called `getCurrentCycle` in one of my viewControllers that I use in a tab based application. I would like to call this method from the `applicationDidBecomeActive` app delegate method.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [NSNotification Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In the controller that has the `getCurrentCycle` method, add the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getCurrentCycle:) name:@"getCurrentCycle" object:nil];
```

When you want to call `getCurrentCycle`, add this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"getCurrentCycle" object:nil];
```

Also, you will need to change your `getCurrentCycle` to:

```
- (void)getCurrentCycle:(NSNotification *)notification
```